# How to debug the WebMethod in web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I have a web application project which invoke a web service login() that come from class WSUserObject reside in WSUserObject.asmx.cs

The following code snippet is from Refereence.cs which reside in the Service Reference of my Web application project.

```
    public APT.WSUserObject.loginResponse Endlogin(System.IAsyncResult result) {
        object[] _args = new object[0];
        APT.WSUserObject.loginResponse _result = ((APT.WSUserObject.loginResponse)(base.EndInvoke("login", _args, result)));
        return _result;
    }
```

Here is my try:

1. attach w3wp.exe
2. Start debug

When I debug, it can only step into the code in Reference.cs.
I need debug into the original source code of this web service on localhost.
The web application project and the web service project are both in the same solution.
How can I step into the WebMethod?

Answer (score 0):

Generally in order to attach solution to w3wp.exe process for break point debugging, the IIS hosted application should have complied dll and pdb files same as in solution.

Comment: How can I complie dll and pdb for is hosted application ? My source code are all reside in localhost .not remote, should I need attach w3pw.exe?